# 'option « --color=auto » hasn't been recognized

Tags: c, security, command, system

I've some trouble to understand why do I get this error, I've tried to change my command ls into cat (for a rootme challenger) but when I try to exec the code as a system command, after adding the executable into the PATH env variable, I've got this error:
'option « --color=auto » hasn't been recognized
but I don't have it when I run my executable by itself, can you guys explain me please?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uIr6.png)

Comment: Please don't use screenshots; they are really difficult to read on mobile devices. Copy and paste your console output into your question as a code block. Thanks.

Comment: will do on next questions!

Answer (score 0):

Your shell start-up files install the alias

```
alias ls='ls --color'
```

So when you type

```
ls rootme.c
```

Your shell substitutes

```
ls --color rootme.c
```

before it even starts to look for the `ls` executable.

On the other hand, typing

```
./ls rootme.c
```

does not trigger the alias.

Comment: thanks, that was exactly that ! I didn"t think to check the .bashrc file.